# Close Socks Connection Ruby

Tags: ruby, networking, socks

1)How do I check what port ruby uses for TCP connections?
2)How do I make the last line of this code work?

```
require 'socksify'  #gem

TCPSocket::socks_server = 'localhost'
TCPSocket::socks_port = 9999 

#do stuff 

TCPSocket::socks_port = CLOSE SOCKS CONNECTION, GO BACK TO WHAT IT WAS BEFORE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TCPSocket::socks_server` and `TCPSocket::socks_port` are nil prior to being set, so I think just do something like this:

```
TCPSocket::socks_server = nil
TCPSocket::socks_port = nil
```